# How to copy commutative diagrams from the n-Lab?

Tags: math-mode, diagrams, commutative-diagrams

At ncatlab.org one can find web pages which feature mathematical formalisms. By double clicking (at least with Firefox) on them, one obtain code that usually works on latex.
Exception are diagrams: copying their associated code does not produce a diagram in Latex.

For instance the commutative diagram of a product is coded as:

```
 \array{ && Q \\ & \swarrow &\downarrow^{\mathrlap{\exists !}}& \searrow \\ X_1 &\overset{p_1}{\longleftarrow}& X_1 \times X_2 &\overset{p_2}{\longrightarrow}& X_2 } \
```

What is this language?
It is possible to adapt the code to make it work on Latex?
This way one would save a lot of time writing about category theory and moreover all diagrams would be written in a homogeneous way. Moreover I personally like the way they appear on the website.

Comment: Even changing `\array` into something else (the name is already taken), the output would be really awful, as you can clearly see in one of the answers. It might save time, but at the expense of typography. Unfortunately, a translator into a better language for diagrams, such as `tikz-cd` is essentially impossible, because that code is a collection of hacks that ends up into something vaguely remembering a commutative diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nLab uses `itex2MML` to render math. So the code you are copying is not directly LaTeX:

```
The case of a binary products it is also denoted by "$(-)\times(-)$":

$$
  \array{
    && Q
    \\
    & \swarrow &\downarrow^{\mathrlap{\exists !}}& \searrow
    \\
    X_1 &\overset{p_1}{\longleftarrow}& X_1 \times X_2 &\overset{p_2}{\longrightarrow}& X_2
  }
  \,.
$$
```

Most notably: `\array` is a command, not an environment.

But you can convert a whole page to LaTeX (there is a button at the end of each page), which yields:

```
The case of a binary products it is also denoted by ``$(-)\times(-)$'':

\begin{displaymath}
\itexarray{
    && Q
    \\
    & \swarrow &\downarrow^{\mathrlap{\exists !}}& \searrow
    \\
    X_1 &\overset{p_1}{\longleftarrow}& X_1 \times X_2 &\overset{p_2}{\longrightarrow}& X_2
  }
  \,.
\end{displaymath}
```

As you can see, `\array` is translated to `\itexarray`.
This won't compile, because you are missing the definition of `\itexarray` and `\mathrlap`. You can find them in the preamble of the generated file. Putting the parts together will result in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\itexarray}[1]{\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}}

% math-mode versions of \rlap, etc
% from Alexander Perlis, "A complement to \smash, \llap, and lap"
%   http://math.arizona.edu/~aprl/publications/mathclap/
\def\clap#1{\hbox to 0pt{\hss#1\hss}}
\def\mathllap{\mathpalette\mathllapinternal}
\def\mathrlap{\mathpalette\mathrlapinternal}
\def\mathclap{\mathpalette\mathclapinternal}
\def\mathllapinternal#1#2{\llap{$\mathsurround=0pt#1{#2}$}}
\def\mathrlapinternal#1#2{\rlap{$\mathsurround=0pt#1{#2}$}}
\def\mathclapinternal#1#2{\clap{$\mathsurround=0pt#1{#2}$}}

\begin{document}
The case of a binary products it is also denoted by ``$(-)\times(-)$'':

\begin{displaymath}
    \itexarray{
        && Q
        \\
        & \swarrow &\downarrow^{\mathrlap{\exists !}}& \searrow
        \\
        X_1 &\overset{p_1}{\longleftarrow}& X_1 \times X_2 &\overset{p_2}{\longrightarrow}& X_2
    }
    \,.
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

TL;DR

You can download the code for each page and copy the LaTeX (not itex) code from there (you might need bits from the preamble too):

[image]

Comment: This is definitely what I was searching for, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you' like to have, it can be done with `tikz-cd`. Here is a short code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=4em, column sep=large]
    &\dlar Q\dar[dashed, "\exists!", swap] \drar\\
    X_1 &\lar["\enspace p_1",swap] X_1\times X_2\rar["p_2"] & X_2
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, `\dlar` and friends hide the simplicity of `tikz-cd`, making one believe that one has to remember so many commands; `\arrow[dl,...]` is much simpler and also allows `\arrow[ld,...]`.

Comment: Once one has perceived they're acronyms, I don't think it's a difficulty. There more problematic convention in tikz-cd (e.g. why  `row sep`, and not a single keyword?)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a code using only the simple commands (see the matrix). It is evident that the preview it is similar to the answer of the user @DG'. I have seen your comment "*This is definitely what I was searching for, thanks!*" and I have searched for another alternative hoping that for your project it is possible to codify it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{matrix}
 &  & Q &&\\
 & \swarrow  &  \quad \downarrow \exists ! & \searrow & \\
X_1 & \xleftarrow{p_1} & X_1 \times X_2 & \xrightarrow{p_2}& X_2 
\end{matrix} .\]
\end{document}
```

[image]